# control + punctuation doesn't register in terminal

Tags: terminal

For the purposes of using emacs in a terminal, I want to use key combinations like <kbd>Control-'</kbd>. But when I try that key combination, it just writes an `'` to the command line. The same thing happens for all punctuation. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [the way ASCII terminals work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd> and other such combinations are meaningless.

The ASCII value of a single quote is 39<sub>10</sub> and since `39`<sub>10</sub> `and` `63`<sub>10</sub> still equals 39<sub>10</sub> you still get a single quote as the result. Only characters with ASCII codes between 64<sub>10</sub> and 126<sub>10</sub> (inclusive) produce meaningful control codes (0<sub>10</sub> through 31<sub>10</sub>). I've omitted some subtleties for simplicity.

When you're not using an ASCII terminal you can map those key combinations since you're using keyboard scan codes or some equivalent.

Comment: How can I find a terminal emulator that works the way I need? Is there such a thing? I've been randomly trying different ones but none have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an Emacs package which can teach Emacs and terminals how to properly recognize all PC keyboard keys and modifier key combinations:

https://github.com/CyberShadow/term-keys

The default configuration already includes encoding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> (so that it's distinguishable from just <kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>, and bindable in Emacs to `` C-` ``).

Comment: Awesome, it works. From the bottom of my heart, thank you good man!